# codeigniter htaccess exception for a specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Below is my htaccess file for codeigniter setup , which converts a/b to index.php/a/b
However, I want to add an exception that if a=cometchat then, it will not do the rewrite.

Please help

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

  # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    # Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system|\.git|\.hg).*$

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cometchat)` is what i have before RewruteRule (replaced with your exception)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|folder1|folder2|img|shared)
```

above each `RewriteRule`, and change/add folders.

so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

  # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    # Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system|\.git|\.hg).*$

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|folder1|folder2|img|shared)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|folder1|folder2|img|shared)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```